# Implementing Google Re-captcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have noticed a number of spam registrations on a form I created to capture customers information before they download a product brochure.

I have attempted to restrict the number of spam entrants by validating fields and implementing Google Re-captcha. 
However, this hasn't stopped the number of spam I am still receiving. Please see the form PHP. below.

```
      <?php 
                // grab recaptcha library
                require_once "recaptchalib.php";

            $name=$_POST['fname'];
            $email=$_POST['email_from'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];
            $city=$_POST['city'];
            $content=$_POST['comments'];



            $to ='person@email.co.uk';
            $subject ='Brochure Enquiry';

            $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            $message = '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<table rules="all"  cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$name. "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;' ><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $email. "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . $phone . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>City:</strong> </td><td>" .$city. "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" .$content. "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";


             //This method sends the mail. 
            if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))


             //This creates the csv file. 

            if($error == '')
            {
            $file_open = fopen("downloadcsv.csv", "a");
            $no_rows = count(file("downloadcsv.csv"));
            if($no_rows > 1)
            {
            $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
            }
            $form_data = array(
            'name'      =>  $name,
            'email'     =>  $email,
            'phone'     =>  $phone,
            'city'      =>  $city, 
            'content'   =>  $content
            );
            fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
            }

            // secret key - removed for privacy
            $secret = "-----------------------------";

            // empty response
            $response = null;

            // check secret key
            $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

            // if submitted check response
            if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
               $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                      $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);
               }



             //This is the brochure link.   
            {
            header('Location:http://www.brochure.de/pdf/brochure_2018.pdf');
            }


            ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is some `if` statement missing. You are not checking the `$response` variable. You call the `verifyResponse()` method but you don't check the result of that call. And why do you send an email before checking the captcha?

Comment: What do I need to add to check the $response ?

Also I can amend the structure to check the captcha before sending email.

Comment: You add an `if()` statement to check the content of the `$response` variable. Depending on the content you can send the email and redirect the user. You have to check the documentation of the `ReCaptcha` API you are using for the possible return values of the `verifyResponse()` method.